# Phonegap 2.3.0 Globalization class not found on BB10 Webworks app

Tags: cordova, globalization, blackberry-10, sencha-touch-2.2

I am developing a Phonegap 2.3 app on BlackBerry 10 with WebWorks and Sencha Touch 2.2. When I try to call the `getPreferredLanguage()` method as per the docs:

```
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
  function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
  function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Status=2 Message=Class Globalization cannot be found
```

The docs state that the Globalization class is supported on BlackBerry with OS5 and higher so why am I getting class not found errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.xml file change

from

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization" />  
</feature>
```

to

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />  
</feature>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check whether the 'device ready' event has been fired or not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
});

function onDeviceReady() {
  alert('device ready');
  navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
  );
}
```

Comment: That is not it because even after the app has fully initialized, running the code from the console I have mentioned above still returns the error message: `Error: Status=2 Message=Class Globalization cannot be found`

Comment: In the console I get a similar error if I try to print out 'navigator.globalization' and despite that my app works fine. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.